# Regular heatmap works but figure factory heatmaps fails in Plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, heatmap

**Data**

fin_list

```
[[None, 9.1, 8.8, 8.7, 8.8, 9.1, 9.2, 9.2, 9.0, 9.6],
 [None, 8.8, 8.5, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 9.1, 8.9, 8.8, 9.7],
 [None, 8.8, 8.6, 8.9, 9.6, 9.0, 8.8, 8.7, 9.0, 9.9],
 [None, 9.1, 9.7, 8.9, 8.8, 8.7, 9.7, 9.1, 9.7, 9.6],
 [None, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.7, 8.6, 8.0, 9.0, 9.9, 9.5],
 [None, 8.5, 9.4, 8.7, 9.1, 9.7, 8.4, 8.6, 8.4, 9.9],
 [None, 8.6, 8.9, 9.2, 9.8, 8.8, 9.1, 9.4, None, None],
 [None, 7.6, 7.9, 7.5, 5.5, 6.0, 4.1, None, None, None]]
```

sorted(series['episodes'])

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

y_episodes

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

**Code for heatmap using Graph_objects**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
                   x=y_episodes,
                   y=sorted(series['episodes']),
                   z=fin_list,
                   colorscale = 'OrRd',
                   hoverongaps = False))
```

**Output**

[image]

**Code for heatmap using** [plotly.figure_factory](https://plotly.com/python/annotated-heatmap/)

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap( 
                   x=sorted(series['episodes']),
                   y=y_episodes,
                   z=fin_list,
                   colorscale = 'OrRd')
```

> Error : PlotlyError: oops, the x list that you provided does not match the width of your z matrix

But my axis are clearly correct as they worked in the above figure.

```
print(len(sorted(series['episodes']))) #x_axis = 8
print(len(y_episodes)) #y_axis = 11
print(len(fin_list)) #z_axis = 8
```

My end goal is to annotate over heatmap, if there is a workaround to add annotation in the code which uses `graph_objects` (and not figure factory), let me know.

Comment: I haven't figured out a solution, but just a heads up - with figure_factory you can't have None values. This will throw a TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType' because z values are assumed to be 'float' only

Comment: I tried with 0 instead of `None` in the `fin_list`. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.nan` instead which is of type `float`. You can replace the values in your `fin_list` using a nested list comprehension:

```
list_nans=[[np.nan if y is None else y for y in x] for x in fin_list]
```

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

fin_list = [[None, 9.1, 8.8, 8.7, 8.8, 9.1, 9.2, 9.2, 9.0, 9.6],
             [None, 8.8, 8.5, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 9.1, 8.9, 8.8, 9.7],
             [None, 8.8, 8.6, 8.9, 9.6, 9.0, 8.8, 8.7, 9.0, 9.9],
             [None, 9.1, 9.7, 8.9, 8.8, 8.7, 9.7, 9.1, 9.7, 9.6],
             [None, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.7, 8.6, 8.0, 9.0, 9.9, 9.5],
             [None, 8.5, 9.4, 8.7, 9.1, 9.7, 8.4, 8.6, 8.4, 9.9],
             [None, 8.6, 8.9, 9.2, 9.8, 8.8, 9.1, 9.4, None, None],
             [None, 7.6, 7.9, 7.5, 5.5, 6.0, 4.1, None, None, None]]

y_sorted=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

y_episodes=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

list_nans=[[np.nan if y is None else y for y in x] for x in fin_list]


fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap( 
                   #x=y_episodes,
                   #y=y_sorted,
                   z=list_nans,
                   #colorscale = 'OrRd'
)
fig.show()
```

**Room for improvement**

Note that I've commented out the x and y arguments. As you hade set it up, it did not work properly. The reason might be that the  the x and y arguments differ for the the two snippets:

```
# go.Heatmap()
x=y_episodes,
y=sorted(series['episodes'])

# ff.create_annotated_heatmap()
x=sorted(series['episodes']),
y=y_episodes,
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out that particular part. But luckily [ff.create_annotated_heatmap()](https://plotly.com/python/annotated-heatmap/) does not require those arguments as you can see from my suggestion.

Further, you could make the figure itself look better by masking or removing the `nan` values in the visualization. But the provided suggestion does at least take care of the `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'`, so I hope this is what you needed to get you one step further.

Answer (score 1):

As vestland wrote, you need to use np.nan instead of None. The other issue is that your ranges aren't consistent with the dimensions of your list/heatmap. To fix this, you can use np.linspace with the number of steps set equal to the length of the dimensions of your list.

Then you can reverse the order of your y-axis so that the origin is in the upper left hand corner, as you have shown in your original output without annotations.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

fin_list = [[np.nan, 9.1, 8.8, 8.7, 8.8, 9.1, 9.2, 9.2, 9.0, 9.6],
[np.nan, 8.8, 8.5, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 9.1, 8.9, 8.8, 9.7],
[np.nan, 8.8, 8.6, 8.9, 9.6, 9.0, 8.8, 8.7, 9.0, 9.9],
[np.nan, 9.1, 9.7, 8.9, 8.8, 8.7, 9.7, 9.1, 9.7, 9.6],
[np.nan, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.7, 8.6, 8.0, 9.0, 9.9, 9.5],
[np.nan, 8.5, 9.4, 8.7, 9.1, 9.7, 8.4, 8.6, 8.4, 9.9],
[np.nan, 8.6, 8.9, 9.2, 9.8, 8.8, 9.1, 9.4, np.nan, np.nan],
[np.nan, 7.6, 7.9, 7.5, 5.5, 6.0, 4.1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]

x_episodes = np.linspace(0, 10, len(fin_list[0])).tolist()
y_episodes = np.linspace(0, 10, len(fin_list)).tolist()

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap( 
    x=x_episodes,
    y=y_episodes,
    z=fin_list,
    colorscale = 'OrRd')
fig['layout']['yaxis']['autorange'] = "reversed"
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice contribution!  Now for the last touch with not displaying the NaNs....